# Different drill through for each row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report with several levels of drilling down. Data is aggregated up for the top level view, but I need to show a different drill down report depending on the type of one of the columns.

Eg:

**Table 1 - Apples**

```
Name     Cost
Fuji     1.5
Gala     3.5
```

**Table 2 - Squashes**

```
Name        Cost
Pumpkin     2
Gourd       4.5
```

I have a stored procedure which aggregates these and puts them in a table for the top level report to show. Ie:

```
Name         Cost     ItemType
Apples       5        1
Squashes     6.5      2
```

In reality, the two tables have different columns which I need to show in the drill through reports. Is it possible to look at the ItemType column and either drill down to one of two sub-reports, depending on it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to choose between two or more different sub-reports then make the ReportName property of the action on the textbox an expression like this.

```
=IIF(Fields!ItemType.Value = 1, "subReport_Apples", "subReport_Oranges")
```

if you have more than a handful SWITCH will probably be better

```
= SWITCH (
          Fields!ItemType.Value = 1, "subReport_Apples",
          Fields!ItemType.Value = 2, "subReport_Oranges",
          Fields!ItemType.Value = 3, "subReport_Lemons",
          True, "subReport_AnythingElse"
)
```

If you have a LOT of item types, consider adding the names of the subreports to your database creating a new table containing `ItemType` and `subReportName`. You can then join to this in your query and get the actual subreport name. The ReportName property of the text action would then simply be `Fields!SubReportname.Value`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `ItemType` as a parameter in your subreport(s). Then from your main report just link or jump to the sub report and pass along the `Fields!ItemType.Value` in the parameter configuration tab.