# SSRS: Go To Action Expression to Direct to Seperate Drillthrough Reports

Tags: reporting-services, expression, action, ssrs-2012, drillthrough

Currently, I have a tablix that shows Number of Records by Group and if they were Completed on Time. Tried to show best my Tablix in the picture below:

[image]

I only have 5 different groups that show up in my Groups column.
Groups:
Group1
Group2
Group3
Group4
Group5. There are currently actions attached on each value in the Number of Records Column.

I'm trying to include an expression in the Action portion that will help me to direct the end user based on a particular Group. For example, if the user selects a value from Group1, Group2 or Group3...I would like them to be directed to my Drillthrough Report "Drillthrough01". If the user selects a value from Group4 or Group5...I would like them to be directed to my Drillthrough Report "Drillthrough02".

I tried to do an expression below (I know it's wrong, but it's along the same lines of what I'm trying to do)

```
=IIf(Fields!Group.Value = "Group1, Group2, Group3", "Drillthrough01" , "Drillthrough02")
```

Not sure if anyone could help with fixing my expression or if they know a better way. Please let me know if need more information on my end.

Comment: I've just answered a very similar question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680767/different-drill-through-for-each-row/43681356#43681356

Answer (score 0):

With Alan's help, I basically used the IFF statement above with some slight edits and incorporated my IFF with multiple conditions using OR and got it to work.